# Change nice value of a process

Tags: bash

I need to write a script for changing the nice value of a process with the new value and the process to be changed given my the command line as such:

```
$ bash script.sh 'cat' 15
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
$ pidof $1 | nice -$2 $1
```

but that didn't work and now I'm quite lost, since I'm new to this stuff. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for [man 1 renice](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html). Note, you may need elevated privileges (e.g. root) to `renice` processes other than your own. You should validate `pidof` returned a valid PID before calling `renice` with the value. E.g. `pidof "$1"; if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then printf "error: no process found.\n" >&2; exit 1; fi` or simply `pidof "$1" || exit 1`

Comment: `nice` doesn't read anything from standard input, so piping text into `nice` -- or `renice` -- is not going to be useful. Perhaps you want `pidof "$1" | xargs renice -"$2"` or, roughly equivalently, `renice -"$2" "$(pidof "$1")"`